Flask Bad Request only when in production
I've recently implemented a reporting system for my website, I got it working on my laptop, but when I deployed it into vercel, it would give a "bad request" when using fetch. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong?
@app.route("/vulnerability/get",methods=["POST"])
def report_get():
  return get_report(request.json.get("id"))

Here's the code to make the fetch request:
/report/manage/[slug]/+page.ts
import { serverURL } from '../../../../serverContactor';

export async function load({ params,fetch }){
    let code=params.slug;
    let body = {"id":code as string};
    const dataRequest = await fetch(`${serverURL}/vulnerability/get`,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    let data;
    try {
        data = await dataRequest.json();
    } catch(error) {
        return {"Error":true,"name":error as string,"response":dataRequest, "code":code as string}
    }
    return data;
}

Which causes the application to log this:
{
  Error: true,
  name: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at Proxy.<anonymous> (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:693:25)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async load (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/report/manage/_slug_/_page.ts.js:14:12)
      at async load_data (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:600:18)
      at async file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2085:18,
  response: Response {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: Headers {
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://frii-site-frontend-ezejbxuv9-ctih1s-projects.vercel.app',
      'cache-control': 'public, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': '167',
      'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Wed, 10 Jul 2024 07:06:09 GMT',
      server: 'Vercel',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'x-vercel-cache': 'MISS',
      'x-vercel-id': 'arn1:sfo1:sfo1:iad1::iad1::kf868-1720595169898-50deaf4d69a8'
    },
    body: ReadableStream { locked: true, state: 'closed', supportsBYOB: true },
    bodyUsed: true,
    ok: false,
    redirected: false,
    type: 'basic',
    url: 'https://server.frii.site/vulnerability/get'
  },
  code: 'WYC6EG9oYpNClQYtUdBSFovH'
}

Using insomnia works fine though, it only seems to happen with fetch.
The application works if the frontend is run locally, the where the backend is hosted doesn't impcat anything.
I also use the same endpoint in another page, which works fine.
/report/track/+page.ts
import { serverURL } from '../../../serverContactor';

export async function load({ url,fetch }) {
    let code:string|null=url.searchParams.get("code");
    let body = {
        "id":code
    };
    const dataRequest = await fetch(`${serverURL}/vulnerability/get`,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    const data = await dataRequest.json();
    return data;
}  

but the following code works in playcode.io
async function load(params:string,serverURL:string) {
    let code=params;
    let body = {"id":code as string};

    const dataRequest = await fetch(`${serverURL}/vulnerability/get`,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    let data;
        dataRequest.text().then(text=>{
            console.log(`Headers: ${dataRequest.headers} body: ${dataRequest.body} body used: ${dataRequest.bodyUsed} text: ${text} code:${code}`);
        });
    return data;
}

P.S: I'm using SvelteKit for the frontend

I got it working on my laptop What was working on your laptop? You ran both the frontend and backend on your laptop, and it worked? And now your running both the frontend and backend on the same server, and now it doesn't work? Also note that fetch() returns a promise that resolves to a response object, and not a request object, so your variable name is a bit confusing. Also, use .text() instead of .json(), and you might be able to learn more about what the server complains about.

Sorry for the confusing question, I've updated it. The app works perfectly when running the backend remotely, while running the frontend locally (aka my laptop). I have the same endpoint used somewhere else, and it works fine with almost the identical code.

Try logging await dataRequest.text(), and see if there's more info on what's wrong.

It states Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand, but nothing specific is given

Could it be too big cookies?

No. The only piece of data that is being sent is the report id, which is 24 charactes

This would be so much easier to debug if the server would even get to run the code. I tried adding a print statement before the get_report() function, but that wouldn't run.

The (adapted) code works without any issues in playcode.io

Sorry, I'm out of ideas ^^' My last tip is to log body before sending the request, to verify that it actually contains what you thin it should contain.

I've found a very hacky-ish fix
It seems like fetching the index endpoint before making the request seems to make it work? I have no idea why it does, nor do I really care.
Here's an example:
import { serverURL } from '../../../serverContactor';

export async function load({ url }) {
    let code:string|null=url.searchParams.get("code");
    await fetch(`${serverURL}`).then(response=>{console.log(response.status)});
    const dataRequest = await fetch(`${serverURL}/vulnerability/get`,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({"id":code})
    });
    const data = await dataRequest.json();
    return data;
}  

